# In angular 2 no wildcard defined in route

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing

While defining routes in angular 2 if I don't define wildcard route and try to hit an invalid url that doesn't exists. What will be the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely get the following error if you call such a URL:

> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'my-invalid-url'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes.

And the application remains on the page that was loaded successfully most recently.